# How to Start .net 6 Hosted Blazor App in xUnit for E2E Tests

Tags: asp.net, xunit, .net-6.0, playwright

Unfortunately all of the resources I found are either using `WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()` which is not starting the application in a way that's exposing HTTP Endpoints or they are referring to old .net versions.

What is a Simple `WebApplicationFactory`-like way to start the App so it can be used by Playwright?

I am not using a `StartUp` class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Basically you have to Start the WebServer in the Background and pass a dummy server to xUnit. I wrote it down here: https://steinbach.io/asp-net-core-e2e-tests-with-xunit-and-playwright/