# Host .NET 6 Blazor WebAssembly in xUnit/SpecFlow test project

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, automated-tests, xunit

I'm using selenium to test my Blazor WebAssembly app, the problem is I don't know how to host my Blazor app in memory, so I can give its URL to selenium driver. Every tutorial I saw is using hard coded URLs in their code.

Blazor app `Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: This guy asked the same question, but it's still unanswered after two months, I guess no one knows the answer then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897844/how-to-start-net-6-hosted-blazor-app-in-xunit-for-e2e-tests

Comment: It looks like that question has an answer that was posted just yesterday (2022/03/30).